# perpendicular on a plane

Tags: solid-geometry

If the plane $lx+my+nz=p$ where $l^2+m^2+n^2=1$ meets the coordinate axes in X, Y, Z and G is the centroid of the triangle XYZ and if the perpendicular to the plane at G, meets the coordinate planes in A, B, C, then prove that 
$\frac{1}{GA}+\frac{1}{GB}+\frac{1}{GC}=\frac{3}{p}$

The above problem is not clear to me. Please provide me a diagrammatic representation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the plane can be written in the standard form as
$$
\frac{x}{p/l}
+
\frac{y}{p/m}
+
\frac{z}{p/n}
=
1.
$$
So the coordinates of the intercepts are
$\mathbf X = (p/l, 0, 0)$ (just set $y$ and $z$ equal to zero in the above equation and you'll see), $\mathbf Y = (0, p/m, 0)$, $\mathbf Z = (0, 0, p/n)$.

The coordinates of the centroid is the average of those of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, and
$$
\mathbf G = \left(
\frac{p}{3\,l},
\frac{p}{3\,m},
\frac{p}{3\,n}\right).
$$

If we draw a perpendicular line to the plane passing through $G$, then the coordinates can be written as
$$
\left(
\frac{p}{3\,l} - l \,t,
\frac{p}{3\,m} - m \, t,
\frac{p}{3\,n} - n \, t
\right).
$$
This is because $(l, m, n)$ is a vector perpendicular to the plane, and any vector parallel it can be written as $(-l\,t, -m\,t, -n\,t$ (the negative sign is chosen for convenience).  The distance from $G$ can be computed as
$$
\sqrt{(l\,t)^2 + (m\,t)^2 + (n\,t)^2}
 = 
\sqrt{l^2 + m^2 + n^2} |t| = |t|.
\tag{1}$$

Now when this perpendicular line meets the $xy$-plane, the $z$ coordinate must be zero, which means
$$
\frac{p}{3\,n} - n \, t = 0.
$$
and $t = p/(3n^2)$.  By (1), this value gives the distance from the intersection $C$ to $G$, so 
$$
GC = \frac{p}{3 \, n^2}.
$$
Similarly,
\begin{align}
GA &= \frac{p}{3 \, l^2}, \\
GB &= \frac{p}{3 \, m^2}.
\end{align}

Finally,
$$
\frac{1}{GA}
+
\frac{1}{GB}
+
\frac{1}{GC}
=
\frac{3 \, l^2+ 3 \, m^2 + 3 \, n^2}{p}
= \frac{3}{p}.
$$